# Null Pointer Exception in array with items in it

Tags: java, arrays, string, nullpointerexception

I am a little confused with what I am doing wrong here. I have a for each loop that goes through each `String[]` in a `List<String[]>` as so:

```
      try {
           List<String[]> lines;
           //Code that fills lines
           for (String[] line : lines){
               System.out.println(line[0] + " "  + line[1] + " " + line[2]);                       
               data.write(line[0], line[1], line[2]);
            }
            //More Code
         } catch (Exception e){ //TODO: DEBUG
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
         }
```

I have verified that each item in line does exist, but I still get a `NullPointerException` at line `data.write(line[0], line[1], line[2]);`.

I am confused because `System.err.println(e.getMessage());` simply prints `null` and `System.out.println(line[0] + " "  + line[1] + " " + line[2]);` will print the correct data

The exception is at that line, so I do not think it is the `write()` method (the debugger will not get to write if I try to step into it).

Thanks

Comment: Where did you initialize `data`?

Comment: We can't help you unless we see the "Code that fills lines", since that's where the problem is. (That or where you initialize `data`, as drewmore pointed out.)

Comment: What does the code that fills `lines` look like? That's most likely where the problem is.

Comment: Instead of `System.err.println(e.getMessage());` use `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Apparently it wasn't. Thought that if you inited in in the superclass it would work its way down. Embarrassing...

Comment: And you dont have a debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that `data` is `null`:

```
           data.write(line[0], line[1], line[2]);
           ^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

NPE in:

```
data.write(line[0], line[1], line[2]);
```

must be either in `data`, `line[0]`, `line[1]` or `line[2]`, use design by contract or assertions to ensure that the  values are there before accessing them.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
try {
   List<String[]> lines;
   //Code that fills lines
   for (String[] line : lines){
       boolean isWrite = true;
       for(int i=0; line != null && i < line.length;i++)
       {
            if(line[i] == null){
                isWrite = false;
                break;
             }
       }
       if(isWrite && data != null){
            System.out.println(line[0] + " "  + line[1] + " " + line[2]);                                      
            data.write(line[0], line[1], line[2]);
        }
    }
    //More Code
 } catch (Exception e){ //TODO: DEBUG
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
 }
```

Above code checked for all possible null as per your code

Answer (score -1):

either data is null or the line[i] is null in one of the iteration.